# Select all record only displaying in current page records in jquery datatable pagination?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, css, datatable

`var allPages = oTable.fnGetNodes();`

this is used to select all the record in data table but I want to select only current page record with select all button.

Comment: Any reproducible example?

Answer (score 0):

This will select the rows in the current page

```
var p = table.rows({ page: 'current' }).nodes();
```